# What does runtime! debian.vim actually do?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, linux-ubuntu, linux-debian

The vimrc template I used had the message "Ensure options work with the Vim-related packages available in Debian." for

```
runtime! debian.vim
```

Here is the contents of `/usr/share/vim/vim81/debian.vim`

```
" Normally we use vim-extensions. If you want true vi-compatibility
" remove change the following statements
set nocompatible    " Use Vim defaults instead of 100% vi compatibility
set backspace=indent,eol,start  " more powerful backspacing

" Now we set some defaults for the editor
set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time

" modelines have historically been a source of security/resource
" vulnerabilities -- disable by default, even when 'nocompatible' is set
set nomodeline

" Suffixes that get lower priority when doing tab completion for filenames.
" These are files we are not likely to want to edit or read.
set suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc

" We know xterm-debian is a color terminal
if &term =~ "xterm-debian" || &term =~ "xterm-xfree86"
  set t_Co=16
  set t_Sf=[3%dm
  set t_Sb=[4%dm
endif

" Some Debian-specific things
if has('gui')
  " Must define this within the :if so it does not cause problems with
  " vim-tiny (which does not have +eval)
  function! <SID>MapExists(name, modes)
    for mode in split(a:modes, '\zs')
      if !empty(maparg(a:name, mode))
        return 1
      endif
    endfor
    return 0
  endfunction

  " Make shift-insert work like in Xterm
  autocmd GUIEnter * if !<SID>MapExists("<S-Insert>", "nvso") | execute "map <S-Insert> <MiddleMouse>" | endif
  autocmd GUIEnter * if !<SID>MapExists("<S-Insert>", "ic") | execute "map! <S-Insert> <MiddleMouse>" | endif
endif

" Set paper size from /etc/papersize if available (Debian-specific)
if filereadable("/etc/papersize")
  let s:papersize = matchstr(readfile('/etc/papersize', '', 1), '\p*')
  if strlen(s:papersize)
    exe "set printoptions+=paper:" . s:papersize
  endif
endif
```

So which vim debian packages is this really for? Vimtutor? I can't think of any vim-related packages other than vim/neovim itself I use on Ubuntu.

Comment: For example, the vim-tiny package. There are multiple GUI vim packages with different GUI toolkits, IIUC

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have never used vim-tiny though. So I wonder if it's necessary in my vimrc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian ships a command `vam` or [vim-addon-manager](https://salsa.debian.org/vim-team/vim-addon-manager/-/blob/master/doc/index.markdown) which can be used to enable Vim plugins in a Debian system.

Plugins can either come from GitHub or a git repository, or they can come from the Debian package [vim-scripts](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/vim-scripts), which contains a curated list of Vim plugins that are maintained and shipped as a Debian package (vim-addon-manager defines a [registry format](https://salsa.debian.org/vim-team/vim-addon-manager/-/blob/master/doc/registry-format.txt) to allow other packages that ship Vim plugins manage them via that tool.)

The reason why this used to require sourcing `debian.vim` was that this script would update [`'runtimepath'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27runtimepath%27) to include `/var/lib/vim/addons` into the list of directories where to look for plugins. That directory is where vim-addon-manager will add symlinks or files or directories to enable or disable plugins managed by it, so including it in `'runtimepath'` is a requirement to make the tool work as expected.

But Debian has switched from adding `/var/lib/vim/addons` to `'runtimepath'` in `debian.vim`, instead passing it to the Vim build (as an argument to the `--with-global-runtime=` option) so that it gets actually hardcoded into the Vim binary itself. Therefore, the vim-addon-manager setup no longer depends on properly sourcing `debian.vim`, but it depends on a Vim binary compiled with that specific option, which is the case for the Vim binaries shipped by Debian.

You can see [this commit](https://salsa.debian.org/vim-team/vim/-/commit/57cedf4e233fffd882115437c1b8cc8a513273bc) (from November 2019) which introduced this change no longer depending on the `'runtimepath'` setting in `debian.vim`, replacing it with the build time option, and [Debian bug #943967](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=943967) which motivated the change.

Comment: So if I don't use any of these debian vim plugins as I use Vundle, it's not necessary in my vimrc?

Comment: @qwr Correct. In fact, even Debian's vim-addon-manager now *should* work without sourcing debian.vim as the runtimepath has been hardcoded into the binary through the build time configuration. But if you use Vundle/vim-plug/etc. to manage your plugins, you shouldn't need debian.vim at all.